# Alternative to "#ifdef" guards for suppressing call to a specific class

Tags: c++, mocking, refactoring

I am re-factoring an application where the GUI and the back-end is highly coupled, mostly because a specific class `MainGui` is called all over the place to refresh the screen or to show a specific message like

```
getMainGui()->refreshDisplay()
getMainGui()->beginUpdate()
getMainGui()->showMessage()
```

Because of this some modules are untestable without a GUI. We need to create a command line executable which can be used for testing.

I want to make those calls no-op on command line. The most obvious approach is to just guard calls with `#ifdef` but there are hundreds of references... I would like to make the changes as localized as possible. Any thoughts?

ps: I can modify `MainGui` and `getMainGui()`

Comment: Sounds like a perfect candidate for *dependency injection*.  Specifically, create a mock implementation of `MainClass`, and use that instead when testing.

Comment: You need to refactor heavily. I would not use a massive amount of #ifdef.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you create another implementation for MainGui? For test purposes:

```
getMainGui()
```

would return MainGuiMock, inside getMainGui() you could use ifdef to decide which implementation to return.

[edit]

Depending on how your getMainGui() looks like now, you could decide on what implementation to return basing on for example external configuration file or command line options. But that would require some common base class for both MainGui and MainGuiMock.

Actually this depends on your requirements, my first suggestion would require you to have to .exe files, one for testing and the other actual GUI application. Going with dependency injection as suggested after [edit], you will have singe exe that can be configured to execute test cases in command prompt.

Comment: Indeed, or just use dependency injection to avoid any ifdefs at all.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be a helper base class, with virtual methods. It's not like the cost of a single virtual call would affect `refreshDisplay` performance. The `TestGui` implementation is of course a no-op

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the perfect motivation of a [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)

You need to create two implementations of your GUI-Interface: One that does nothing (the null object) and one that actually displays and updates the interface.

Depending on whether you run your application on the command line or with the GUI, getMainGui() should return the appropriate object. All other methods can then continue to call GUI functions, but while testing on the command line, no effects occur.

Wikipedia even gives a sample implementation in C++:

```
class animal {
  public:
    virtual void make_sound() = 0;
};

class dog : public animal {
  void make_sound() { cout << "woof!" << endl; }
};

class null_animal : public animal {
  void make_sound() { }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as per other answers you could create a virtual base class defining these GUI functions then derive both ther "real" GUI version and a no-op version therefrom.  Depending on exact implementation - you may have to go out of your way to avoid a performance hit from calls start dispatching virtually in your real build (of up to about an order of magnitude for trivial get/set functions, very much subject to compiler/compiler switches/CPU/etc).  If you accept such a performance hit you *probably* won't notice it, but you might (or - worse - a user with a slower PC might)....

There are many other options including:

- if the application code is itself in a type that's templated (or reasonable to make templated) you can provide the GUI class type to use as a template parameter
- if the application code uses say a static/anonymous-namespace main GUI global in its implementation file, you could `#ifdef` just that line to substitute a test version

(if you post more of your actual code it'd be easier to make specific recommendations, as a lot depends on exactly what appears in which headers, free-standing vs. class member etc.)